# Custom radio buttons are not visible

Tags: html, css, radio-button, custom-controls, radio-group

I want to customize my radio buttons so they would look like the following:

[image]

To achieve this, I use the following css and html

HTML:

```
<div class="buttonSlider">
    <input type="radio" value=".."></input>
    <input type="radio" value=".."></input>
    <input type="radio" value=".."></input>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.buttonSlider {
    font-size: 250%;
    background: #ccffdd;
}

.buttonSlider input[type="radio"] { /* don't show the radio check items */
    display: none;
}

.buttonSlider label {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#ddd;
    padding:4px 11px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:16px;
}

.buttonSlider input[type="radio"]:checked + .buttonSlider label { 
    background-color:#bbb;
}
```

However, the buttons are not visible when I apply this css to the radio buttons.

Could someone help and elaborate his/her explanation to me? I am pretty new to css.

Comment: The `display:none;` is why they aren't displaying.

Comment: With your example, nothing is visible because there is nothing to show. Add the labels to the example.

Comment: I don't see any labels in your markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working example without checkboxes. maybe it helps

http://jsfiddle.net/zCBBf/1/

```
.radio-box
{
background-color:black;
height:53px;
width:535px;
padding:4px;
}

.radio-box label {    
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#ddd;
  padding:17px 60px;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:16px;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  display:none;
}

.radio-box input[type="radio"]:checked + label{ 
  background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
.buttonSlider input[type="radio"]:checked + label { 
   background-color:#bbb;
}
```

And you are doing `display:none;`

```
.buttonSlider input[type="radio"] { /* don't show the radio check items */
  display: none;
}
```

so you need to remove that as well.

Please see this:

http://jsfiddle.net/JSWorld/zCBBf/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<head >
    <title></title>

    <style>
        .buttonSlider 
        {
        background-color: #800001;
        }
        .buttonSlider .radiobox
        {
            height: 20px;
            width: 100px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color: #800001;
            float: left;
        }
        .buttonSlider input
        {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>


    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.buttonSlider input').replaceWith('<div class="radiobox"> <input type="radio" name="radio1" value=".."/></div>');
            $('.buttonSlider input').prop('checked', false);
            $('.radiobox').click(function () {
                var this_div = $(this);
                if (this_div.find('input').is(':checked')) {
                    this_div.find('input').prop('checked', false);
                    this_div.css({ 'background-color': '#800001' });
                }
                else {
                    this_div.find('input').prop('checked', true);
                    this_div.css({ 'background-color': '#808080' });
                }

            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="buttonSlider">
        <input type="radio" value=".." name="radio1" />
        <input type="radio" value=".." name="radio1" />
        <input type="radio" value=".." name="radio1" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```